# How to check that List<Long> contains a value?

Tags: java, collections

I have list `List<Long> list`, that contains: [160774, 7212775] and `Long id = 7212775`. I need to check if the list contains an element with value of `id`. How to do that? Unfortunately `list.contains(id)` returns `false` in my case.

I'm using it that way:

```
@RequestMapping("/case/{id}")
public String openCase(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {

    log.debug(caseDAO.findAllCasesId());    // [160774, 7212775]
    log.debug(id); // 7212775

    if(caseDAO.findAllCasesId().contains(id)) {
        return "case";
    } else {
        return "404";
    }
}
```

Piece of DAO (Hibernate, but native sql here):

```
public List<Long> findAllCasesId() {
    String sql = "select id from cases";
    SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql);
    return query.list();
}
```

---

**SOLVED**

The problem was with `caseDAO.findAllCasesId()`, that return list of `Object`, not list of `Long`. I corrected this by:

`SQLQuery query = getSession().createSQLQuery(sql).addScalar("id", Hibernate.LONG);`

Big thanks to: [Nayuki Minase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839689/nayuki-minase)

Comment: I am not seeing the problem. Please post your code?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that `caseDAO.findAllCasesId()` has type `List<Long>`? Note that `List.contains(Object)` takes an `Object`, so it's easy to mistakenly test for something that cannot possibly exist.

Comment: It's possible that the particular implementation of `List` does not satisfy the contract for `contains()`. Try to check using a `for`-loop and `equals()` to see if it's a true bug.

Comment: @Nayuki You have right. I check `instanceof` element of list and it is not Long! It is Object, hence the problem was. Very big thanks.

Comment: Okay, glad to hear it's solved. I think on Stack Overflow you should post an answer yourself and then accept it, heh, so that future readers can benefit.

Answer (score 8):

When autoboxing, you need to make sure you postfix the literal with an L i.e. `Long id = 7212775L` for this to work.

Comment: To not confuse people: We're obviously talking about a *post*fix literal here ;)

Answer (score 6):

Running the code below on eclipse helios:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>();
    list.add(160774L);
    list.add(7212775L);
    System.out.println(list.contains(7212775L);
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

What you're doing wrong is

```
System.out.println(list.contains(7212775));
```

The problem is that your list takes Long objects and you are searching for a literal.

Answer (score 3):

```
List<Long> list = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(160774L, 7212775L));
Long id = 7212775L;
System.out.println(list.contains(id)); // prints true
```

Answer (score 0):

Hum, I believe List list should return true in your case.
The following piece of code returns true.

```
List<Long> listOfLongs = new java.util.ArrayList<Long>();
    listOfLongs.add(160774L);
    listOfLongs.add(7212775L);
    return listOfLongs.contains(7212775L);
```

Same with

```
List<Long> listOfLongs = new java.util.ArrayList<Long>();
    listOfLongs.add(Long.valueOf(160774L));
    listOfLongs.add(Long.valueOf(7212775L));
    return listOfLongs.contains(Long.valueOf(7212775L));
```

If you could show us the code where this ain't working, it would help.