# Check for List<Long> contains a value fails

Tags: java, arraylist

I have list List myList, that contains Long values which is returned from a database operation. I am checking if the list contains a specific Long value. I am trying to do myList.contains(value), but unfortunately it returns false even though the List contains the specific value! Why it is happening? How to resolve it?

*Repository class*

```
    @Repository
    public interface CarsRepository extends JpaRepository<Cars, Long> {
        @Query(value = "select id from Cars WHERE colour = ?1", nativeQuery=true)
        public List<Long> fetchCarsWithColour(String colour);
    }
```

*Calling method*

```
    Long specificCarId = 3456L;
    List<Long> carIds = carsRepository.fetchCarsWithColour("red");
    System.out.println(carIds);         // [3456, 3457]
    System.out.println(specificCarId);  // 3456
    if(carIds.contains(specificCarId)){
       System.out.println("Inside if");
       return true;
    }  else {
       System.out.println("Inside else");
       return false;
    }
```

*Console*

```
[3456, 3457]
3456
Inside else
```

The calling method returns false even though it has the value 3456L.

**UPDATE**

I have tried printing List carIds as below. It throws exception `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to java.lang.Long`

```
for(Long value : carIds){
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

So somehow, the repository call returns List instead of List but because of autoboxing, it perfectly fits into List

Comment: Does the List actually contain that value?  Have you verified it? This is also a segment of a method.  What else is going on there?  Perhaps you should print just above the return statements.

Comment: @XavierBrassoud this obviously isn't an async call. those return Futures.

Comment: Your code as pasted is fine; if it isn't returning the result you expected, you'd have to paste more / look elsewhere. For example, this isn't a case-insensitive scan; perhaps in your DB it's got colour 'RED', not 'red'. Or there's a bug in your code (you did not paste your code, you pasted some sort of pseudocode, given that there are obvious errors in there such as missing semicolons).

Comment: I have verified many times; the Id 3456 is there in the List.

Comment: Can you log the ids received in carIds list and paste the output in question?

Comment: _"I have verified many times"_ - SHOW us how you verified this.  We've all made the mistake:  "verifying" something and believing it to be true, but then someone looks over your shoulder and points out the error.

Comment: Added System.out.println(carIds)

Comment: Can you put an informative print statement with the value right before returning true and false?  e.g `System.out.println("returning true with -" + specificCarId);`  The other issue is that we don't see where you're making the call and checking the return value.  The `contains` may actually be working fine.  This is where a [mre] would be useful instead of the code fragments.

Comment: Ok, are you certain this is the **exact** code? I just noticed you're missing a semi-colon at the end of the `fetchCarsWithColour("red")` statement.  So this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113715/how-to-check-that-listlong-contains-a-value/7113778 Found similar question here!

Comment: You should try, " for(Long carId: carIds){ System.out.println(carId.equals(specificCarId));}" that should give you a class cast exception if your "objects" aren't Longs.

Comment: Your library is returning a BigInteger, not a Long. It should be "List<BigInteger> carIds"

Comment: yes @matt I have changed it to BigInteger and changed the comparison logic to BigInteger comparison. Now it is working fine. Is there a way to forcefully return Long other than BigInteger from Repository?

Comment: @User_1940878 That comes down to your database and config. You might actually try to make a question out of that.